# htaccess only accept traffic from specific http_referer

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to set up a htaccess file that would accomplish the following:

Only allow my website to be viewed if the viewing user is coming from a specific domain (link)

So, for instance.  I have a domain called.  protect.mydomain.com .  I only want people coming from a link on unprotected.mydomain.com to be able to access protect.mydomain.com.

The big outstanding issue I have is that if you get to protect.mydomain.com from unprotected.mydomain.com and click on a link in the protect.mydomain.com that goes to another page under protect.mydomain.com then I get sent back to my redirect because the http_referer is protect.mydomain.com .   So to combat that I put in a check to allow the referrer to be protect.mydomain.com as well.  It's not working and access is allowed from everywhere.  Here is my htaccess file. (All this is under https)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://(.+\.)*mydomain\.com
RewriteCond %1 !^(protect|unprotected)\.$ 
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://unprotected.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What's a url of yours that would link to `https://protect.mydomain.com/`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are matching your referer against `^https://(.+\.)*mydomain\.com`. Which means if some completely other site, say `http://stealing_your_images.com/` links to something on **protect.mydomain.com**, the first condition will fail, thus the request is never redirected to `https://unprotected.mydomain.com/`. You want to approach it from the other direction, only allow certain referers to pass through, then redirect everything else:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# allow these referers to passthrough
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://(protect|unprotected)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^ https://unprotected.mydomain.com/ [R,L]
```

Comment: @Josh Be Aware from being faked with http_referer with cumstom headers
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807604/preventing-curl-referrer-spoofing