# Set php variable depending on where page is loaded from

Tags: javascript, php, html, session-variables

I have two ways to get to my chat.php page.
One way is via profile page link and the other is via the menu.
My question is, how can I know in chat.php, where the page is loaded from?

Comment: You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: I advise against using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] as it can be easily spoofed

Comment: @ClementSam I agree with you but unfortunately, it is a "take it or go home" deal. Referral:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807604/preventing-curl-referrer-spoofing

Comment: I have been trying something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62834971/how-to-override-previous-page-redirect

Answer (score 0):

I understand require this information using javascript, if it is the case use referrer

```
const referrer = document.referrer;
```

MDN

> The Document.referrer property returns the URI of the page that linked
> to this page.

[Document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)