# Allow access to website only from a specific URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, web, portfolio

I have got a client who I did a great website for a year or so ago however he has just sold his business and as part of the deal he wants me to take the website down. He has however agreed to allow me to use the website on my portfolio so I essentially want to be able to block all entries except from entries from my domain name, is this possible? I was thinking the best solution will be .htaccess but I am not the best at .htaccess so any advise would be awesome.

Comment: There is also a discussion here on this site: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374535/htaccess-only-accept-traffic-from-specific-http-referer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Put it in the directory that requires the denial.
I would suggest an alternative method though; perhaps moving the site to your own server.

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName OnlyFromUNO

<Limit GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from .domain.com
</Limit>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me :( I just get a 500 error each time. Any ideas?