# Allowing traffic from PayPal only

Tags: .htaccess, paypal

I've seen this page [htaccess only accept traffic from specific http_referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374535/htaccess-only-accept-traffic-from-specific-http-referer) and I think this is the code I need to replicate what I am looking to do ... can anyone please confirm or advise if I'm barking up the right tree ....

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# allow these referers to passthrough
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://*.*paypal*\.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^ http://www.clientsite.com/ [R,L]
```

Basically I only want users who have successfully completed a PayPal checkout to be able to access the PDF files in the folder.

Comment: I feel like this isn't a great solution to your original problem. The HTTP referrer can be faked, so anyone can access the page, and it seems like a usability problem if people who purchased these PDFs cannot come back later to download them, since they will no longer be referred from PayPal.

Comment: Hi Steve, Personally I agree, however the client feels differently.

Whilst I appreciate that the HTTP Referrer can be faked, its not a very simple thing to do so shouldn't be a big issue for the client.